# Progressdialog for phonegap projects

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am very new to `html5`, `css` and `javascript`. i have knowledge in android development.
Now i have started working on `phonegap` projects.

In my project i want show a loader just like a `progressdialog` in android when application moves from one screen to another screen or loading something.

Can any one help me to do this in html5?

Comment: are you using jquery mobile or sencha touch or another js library?

Comment: i am not using any js library.

Comment: How are you moving your screens? No one can give you sample code if you're not using a common html5 mobile library, framework, or we don't have your sample code to know how you are stepping through the different views.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar need . I was able to do it using navigator object. Please find below sample code
to load data in background

```
function someJSFunctionLoadingData() {
   navigator.notification.activityStart("Your message....", "loading");
   ////// some activity
   navigator.notification.activityStop();
```

}

Further to navigate around you could use introduce a small delay ( 2 secs) and let progress bar load during that time and then direct user to the url you need. Below is the example for same

```
function loadMyUrl(){
    navigator.notification.activityStart("Loading some url....", "loading");
    setTimeout(function loadMyUrl(){
                      navigator.app.loadUrl('file:///android_asse/www/someurl.html');
                      navigator.notification.activityStop();
                      }, 2000 ); 
 }
```

I got above idea from [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/TtCu2_Sx4_I) link

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to just create a css based spinner element and set it to hidden/visible when needed via your js.

I searched and found tons of examples [online here is one for example](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/12/creating-a-loading-spinner-animation-in-css-and-javascript.html).

Comment: added an example to the link, but just search in google for "css spinner" and you can find tons.